# JavaScript - unable to select row from reactable table from checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I have a checkbox on every row on my reactable table. When clicked this fires a function called `_onSelectARow`, which should return all the data on that row.
Although the function fires, I am not getting the data. Which is what I want to pass on to another redux function. My function is as follows:

```
 _onSelectARow = (index) => {
    return(event) => {
      let selectrow = this.state.data.MyTableData.slice();

      if(event.target.checked){
        if(selectrow.indexof(index)==-1){
          selectrow.push(index);
        }
      } else {
        let found = selectrow.indexof(index);
        if(found >-1){
          selectrow.splice(found,1);
        }
      }
      this.setState({selectrow:selectrow});
```

Index is passed in on the row of the checkbox by `{this._onSelectARow(index)}`, and is set when `data.map(row,index)` is called binding the rows to the table.

The problem I am getting when the function is called, is that I am not getting the data of the row, but merely an index, and I cannot see why.

Is someone able to point out where the problem is and how I can fix it, please?

Thanks

Comment: The line `return(event) => {`  looks strange. Do you want to return something? Or do you want to define a function called "return". The code is also not complete (missing some closing brackets at the end). What happens if you delete the `return(event)` line altogether?

Comment: I have only given the main code snippet which I have copied manually by hand

Comment: Why not simply return `this.state.data.MyTableData[index]`? It looks like you have your index and content mixed up. E.g. `selectrow.push(index)` adds the index (a number?) to an array `selectrow` (array of cells?).

Comment: Also `selectrow.indexof(index)` is strange. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) for an explanation of how you should use `.indexOf()`